# Include zeros in SQL count query?

Tags: mysql

I want to be able to return 0 when I am doing a count, I'd preferably not use joins as my query doesn't use them.

This is my query.

```
SELECT count( user_id ) as agencyLogins, 
      DATE_FORMAT(login_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as date 
FROM logins, users 
WHERE login_date >= '2015-02-10%' AND login_date < '2016-02-11%' 
AND logins.user_id = users.id 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(login_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

What it does is counts the amount of times a user has logged into the website.
It doesn't count zeros though where as I want to know when there has been no log ins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try using explicit join in the future, more readable and will make you avoid this errors. What you need is a left join:

```
SELECT t.id,count(s.user_id) as agencyLogins, DATE_FORMAT(s.login_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as date
FROM users t
LEFT OUTER JOIN login s
ON(t.id = s.user_id)
WHERE (s.login_date >= '2015-02-10%' AND s.login_date < '2016-02-11%') or (s.user_id is null)
GROUP BY t.id,DATE_FORMAT(s.login_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: I get an error - Unknown column 't.user_id' in 'field list' I don't know why this isn't working. (My SQL knowledge isn't great)

Comment: @Kieron606 Sry, thought the column name is user_id, its actually ID, so now the query will work.

Comment: You need COUNT(s.id) rather than COUNT(*) . As you want a count of logins for the user, rather than a count of rows (ie, if a user had not logged in 1 row would still be returned, hence the count would be 1 with your current solution).

Comment: @Kickstart You're right, slipped from my eyes. Keyron, does it work?

Comment: @sagi The only problem being it runs really slowly?

Comment: I suspect the issue with performance might be an index issue. Does the login table have an index on the user_id column? Or better an index covering both the user_id and the login_date? Also, being MySQL I might be tempted to fiddle things a touch and GROUP BY s.login_date (without formatting it) - assuming login_date is a date field rather than a datetime.

Comment: Also, why do you check a date range with a % on the end of it? Looks like an odd mix of a character representation of the date and a LIKE statement (and you are not doing a LIKE). Further move the check for the date range to the ON clause of the join and elminate the _OR (s.user_id IS NULL)_

Comment: @Kickstart thanks for the swift reply. I will look up indexing. I also need something else relevant to this question to ask but do I need to open a new question since I selected an answer or can I make an edit?

Comment: Best to do another question

Comment: Prefered you open a new question unless its a small chabge. @kickstart , agree with every word.

Comment: @Kickstart Thanks I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think below SQL useful to you. **2015-02-10%** please remove % symbol in that string.

```
    SELECT IF(COUNT(user_id) IS NULL,'0',COUNT(user_id)) as agencyLogins, DATE_FORMAT(login_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as date FROM users left join logins on logins.user_id = users.id 
    WHERE date(login_date) >= date('2015-02-10') AND date(login_date) <= date('2016-02-11')
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(login_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: That is not what he asked for .

Comment: This is actually useful and improved my SQL query, although not what i asked for.

Comment: i modified the SQL please check it.

Comment: @VenkateshPanabaka this doesn't count zero's still? It works but doesn't do what I have asked for.

Comment: @Kieron606 i modified SQL please check it.

Comment: @VenkateshPanabaka Please verify that your solution actually works before you post an answer.

Comment: Yea, and hint: it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

This might be help you out

```
    SELECT SUM(agencyLogins), date FROM (
    SELECT count( user_id ) as agencyLogins, 
          DATE_FORMAT(login_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as date 
    FROM logins, users 
    WHERE login_date >= '2015-02-10%' AND login_date < '2016-02-11%' 
    AND logins.user_id = users.id 
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(login_date,'%Y-%m-%d')


    UNION ALL

    SELECT 0,''
    ) AS A 
    GROUP BY DATE
```

Comment: This only brought back 0 once.